Converting h:m:s (character) to seconds (numeric) in R
I have imported data from excel. One of the columns is "Wait.Time" and it represents the amount of time a patient was waiting in hours:minutes:seconds format. When I imported the CSV file it logged this column as being of class "character".
How do I convert this column's values to just seconds so I can tell R to treat is as a numeric value? (e.g. 00:24:03 --> 1,443).
I tried this code:
library(chron)
df$Wait.Time <- chron(df$Wait.Time = time)

Which gave this error:
Error: unexpected '=' in "df$Wait.Time <- chron(df$Wait.Time ="


What are you trying to accomplish with chron(df$Wait.Time = time)? When specifying function arguments the LHS is the function argument and the RHS is the value. The error you are getting is because df$Wait.Time = time within a function is not valid syntax.

I get this Warning message: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :   Some strings failed to parse when I do `df$Wait.Time <- hms(df$Wait.Time)'

It would be helpful if you could add values from that column to your question. This works for the only sample you posted: 00:24:03. However, it seems you might have some values in that column that do not match the format "H:M:S"

I've reinspected the data. It worked for all observations apart from the few which go over two different days (i.e. 23:24:03 to 01:34:00) so it's a problem with the data I was putting in. This was only a problem for 5 values so I will fix by hand. Thank you for the lubridate tip

Convert to the string into a POSIXct object and then find the time difference since midnight.
time<- as.POSIXct("00:24:03", "%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
difftime(time, (Sys.Date()), units="secs")
#Time difference of 1443 secs


Although the chance of this happening is small if run at midnight the as.POSIXct could be run on a different date than Sys.Date in which case it would give the wrong answer.
